Fetch additional branches in Jenkins multibranch pipeline
I have a Jenkins multibranch pipeline build where one of the steps needs to compare commits between the branch being built and main and develop. However, when the script runs, it complains that the commit doesn't exist in the repository. How do I configure Jenkins so that it checks out the branch of the current build but also fetches additional branches?
I can't run a git command because the build servers don't have Git credentials stored on them. Credentials have to come from Jenkins so fetching the additional branches needs to happen via Jenkins or our Jenkinsfile.
I can see in the Jenkins UI for my multibranch pipeline that there is a "Specify ref specs" option, which defaults to +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/@{remote}/*. That appears to retrieve all remote branches. This repo is rather large and has dozens of branches. I only want to retrieve the branch of the current build, main, and develop. Is there a special ref spec that allows me to do that? Is there a step I can put in my Jenkinsfile that will fetch branch heads? Or is there another option?

It allows to specify multiple refpecs like +refs/heads/main:refs/remotes/@{remote}/main  +refs/heads/develop:refs/remotes/@{remote}/develop in git fetch. Jenkins is supposed to support multiple refspecs too.

You could configure Jenkins to fetch more branches, but if you still need to run git commands from your pipeline you can use this step:
withCredentials([gitUsernamePassword(credentialsId: 'my-credentials-id', gitToolName: 'git-tool')]) {
  sh 'git fetch --all'
}

